# How to resize an image maintaining the aspect ratio in C#

Tags: c#, image

I need to know of a way to resize an image to fit in a box without the image stretching too much. The box has set width and height and I want the image to fill as much of the box as possible but maintain the aspect ratio it originally had.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
//calculate the ratio
double dbl = (double)image.Width / (double)image.Height;

//set height of image to boxHeight and check if resulting width is less than boxWidth, 
//else set width of image to boxWidth and calculate new height
if( (int)((double)boxHeight * dbl) <= boxWidth )
{
    resizedImage = new Bitmap(original, (int)((double)boxHeight * dbl), boxHeight);
}
else
{
    resizedImage = new Bitmap(original, boxWidth, (int)((double)boxWidth / dbl) );
}
```

The formula for scaling with the same ratio is:

```
newWidth =  (int)((double)boxHeight * dbl)

or

newHeight =  (int)((double)boxWidth / dbl)
```

Comment: A little explanation of the code? Or maybe some comments in your code?

Comment: @MuhammadBashir  Your suggested edit may have good code but it should probably be written as a new answer as it would be a big change to this accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

A Math.Max could simplify the problem:

```
double ratio = Math.Max((double)image.width / (double)box.width , (double)image.height / (double)box.height);
image.width = (int)(image.width / ratio);
image.height = (int)(image.height / ratio);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Bitmap original,resizedImage;
try
                {

                    using (FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(imageLabel.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
                    {

                        original = new Bitmap(fs);
                    }

                    int rectHeight = BOXWIDTH;
                    int rectWidth = BOXWIDTH;
                    //if the image is squared set it's height and width to the smallest of the desired dimensions (our box). In the current example rectHeight<rectWidth
                    if (original.Height == original.Width)
                    {
                        resizedImage = new Bitmap(original, rectHeight, rectHeight);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //calculate aspect ratio
                        float aspect = original.Width / (float)original.Height;
                        int newWidth, newHeight;
                        //calculate new dimensions based on aspect ratio
                        newWidth = (int)(rectWidth * aspect);
                        newHeight = (int)(newWidth / aspect);
                        //if one of the two dimensions exceed the box dimensions
                        if (newWidth > rectWidth || newHeight > rectHeight)
                        {
                           //depending on which of the two exceeds the box dimensions set it as the box dimension and calculate the other one based on the aspect ratio
                            if (newWidth > newHeight)
                            {
                                newWidth = rectWidth;
                                newHeight = (int)(newWidth / aspect);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                newHeight = rectHeight;
                                newWidth = (int)(newHeight * aspect);

                            }
                        }
                        resizedImage = new Bitmap(original, newWidth, newHeight);



                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show( ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti One *if-else* is enough

Comment: In theory only one if else is needed by I just added extra code to be completely safe for square images.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer probably works but I stared at it for a long time and could not understand exactly how, so I thought I would share what I came up with: shrink height first, then check width and shrink again if needed, always preserving the aspect ratio.

I used [`SixLabors.ImageSharp`](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) because it's compatible with Linux, but you can easily swap out the resizing function once you have the `newHeight` and `newWidth`.

```cs
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

public class ImageSharpService : IImageService
{
    public async Task ShrinkAndSaveAsync(Stream stream, string savePath, int maxHeight, int maxWidth)
    {
        using Image image = Image.Load(stream);

        // check if resize is needed
        if (ResizeNeeded(image.Height, image.Width, maxHeight, maxWidth, out int newHeight, out int newWidth))
            // swap this part out if not using ImageSharp
            image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(new ResizeOptions
            {
                Size = new Size(newWidth, newHeight)
            }));

        await image.SaveAsync(savePath);
    }

    private bool ResizeNeeded(int height, int width, int maxHeight, int maxWidth, out int newHeight, out int newWidth)
    {
        // first use existing dimensions
        newHeight = height;
        newWidth = width;

        // if below max on both then do nothing
        if (height <= maxHeight && width <= maxWidth) return false;

        // naively check height first
        if (height > maxHeight)
        {
            // set down to max height
            newHeight = maxHeight;

            // calculate what new width would be
            var heightReductionRatio = maxHeight / height; // ratio of maxHeight:image.Height
            newWidth = width * heightReductionRatio; // apply ratio to image.Width
        }

        // does width need to be reduced? 
        // (this will also re-check width after shrinking by height dimension)
        if (newWidth > maxWidth)
        {
            // if so, re-calculate height to fit for maxWidth
            var widthReductionRatio = maxWidth / newWidth; // ratio of maxWidth:newWidth (height reduction ratio may have been applied)
            newHeight = maxHeight * widthReductionRatio; // apply new ratio to maxHeight to get final height
            newWidth = maxWidth;
        }

        // if we got here, resize needed and out vars have been set
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that if you only change the height or only the width it will remain in better ratios and the width/height will change with it. So you can try that

Comment: No, you can't keep one size fixed. Imagine you have a 100x50 image and you have to draw it in a 200x200 box: would you draw image 200x50? 100x200? Keeping aspect ratio it'll be 200x100

Comment: yes, but if you want the 200*200 and just change it to that than the ratios will be off.But yes if you want 200*200 on a 100*50 picture this wont work. This is only if you want to keep the ratios

Comment: That's the whole point of question. Changing to as close to the desired dimensions as possible while maintaining the aspect ratio

Comment: Yes, and if you want to maintain the ratio. Than you will always have the same as my code(in a different way) cause you will always have the same % of eachother. Or am i confused now? Like:
if you do the height X2, to maintain the ratio, you will have to do width*2