# C# How to scale rectangles with PictureBox?

Tags: winforms, resize, drawing, scaling, c#-2.0

I have a PictureBox and I draw rectangles on it.

I use SizeMode.Zoom property to scale my PictureBox

This is my code:

```
  float width = (int)(Math.Abs(left - right) * ratio); // Resizing works good
  float height = (int)(Math.Abs(top - bottom) * ratio);
  float x =  w / 2; // w, h - PictureBox.Width, PictureBox.Height
  float y = h / 2; // The rectangle is always in the center
```

I want the rectangles to stick to the image.
How do I change the position of these rectangles when my PictureBox is resizing?

How to find out the position of a rectangle relative to the center of the box?

[without sticking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygz6Q.gif)

Comment: @HansPassant When the image resizes as a box I calculate the proportions but they do not work with my scaling function(

Comment: Maybe this will help you [How to resize an image maintaining the aspect ratio in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486671/how-to-resize-an-image-maintaining-the-aspect-ratio-in-c-sharp/26487169#26487169)